# Pictures only covers a small section of the body when they need to cover the whole section of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have 3 pictures cover 1 page so each picture has to take up 1/3 of the page and in between each picture there is a divider (which is a picture as well).

here is jsfiddle of my code https://jsfiddle.net/optjhz2m/

```
#background_pic1 {
    background-image:url(Pictures/daintree_rainforest_background_wallpaper-wide.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: What does that JSFiddle have to do with your problem?

Comment: it shows all my code and what i have done

Comment: You can just merge the three images as one along with the divider and use it as a full webpage cover.

Answer (score 0):

Without too much context to the issue, I believe CSS3's multiple background declarations might be a solution for you, assuming you're okay with modern browsers. You could use background shorthand similar to what I have below.

```
.class{
     background: url('http://placehold.it/300x30') center 0% / 300px 30px no-repeat,
                 url('http://placehold.it/300x2') center 20% / 80% auto no-repeat, / * spacer * /
                 url('http://placehold.it/300x30') center 33% / 300px 30px no-repeat,
                 url('http://placehold.it/300x2') center 50% / 80% auto no-repeat,/ * spacer * /
                 url('http://placehold.it/300x30') center 66% / 300px 30px no-repeat;}
```

But a simpler solution, mentioned above, could be to combine them into one image. It's hard to know without more context.

Comment: When I look at your jsfiddle, you're using empty elements to apply images via CSS. If your images are only decorative, then applying your images with CSS background images is okay and you can do that on the main related element (non-empty elements), but if the images are related to content, then it's a different story.  I would avoid having conflicts with your content (HTML) and styles (CSS). By defining what you want to do, you'll help others help you and you'll define your own objectives which helps development. Hope that helps.